Determining the Laplace Transform of a triangle signal
I have been given the following signal:

I have written this using the Heaviside function. This gave me the following:
$$ x(t) = t[u(t)-u(t-1)] + t[u(t-1)-u(t-2)] = tu(t) - tu(t-2) $$
Applying the laplace transform on each part, I get:
$$ LT[tu(t)] = \frac{1}{s^2} $$
$$ LT[tu(t-2)] = \frac{e^{-2s}}{s^2} + \frac{2e^{-2s}}{s} $$
I want to know if I determined x(t) and X(s) correctly, because I am not sure if I am doing the second LT correctly, or if I am determining x(t) correctly.

This is wrong.
$$x(t)=t\cdot(u(t)-u(t-1))+(t\color{red}{-1})\cdot(u(t-1)-u(t-2))$$

ahhhh, thank you. I feel a bit stupid now.
